# How to use list of values in get method?

Tags: python, django

I have a template filter in Django that looks ugly and not very pythonic. Is there a way to combine all the get requests into a list?

```
@register.filter(name='is_supervisor')
def is_in_group(user):
    group = Group.objects.get(name="security supervisor")
    group1 = Group.objects.get(name="cage supervisor")
    group2 = Group.objects.get(name="casino supervisor")
    group3 = Group.objects.get(name="food bev supervisor")
    return True if group or group1 or group2 or group3 in user.groups.all() else False
```

I tried using a `Q` filter for chaining them together but that did not work. I have also tried:

```
@register.filter(name='is_supervisor')
def is_in_group(user):
    types = ["security supervisor", "cage supervisor",
             "casino supervisor", "food bev supervisor"]
    for name in types:
        test1 = Group.objects.get(name=name)
    return True if test1 in user.groups.all() else False
```

Comment: Somehow people keep asking this question every single day, `x or y in z`, is parsed as `(x) or (y in z)`, and it thus evalautes the truthiness of `group` here, and that is `True`.

Comment: Sometimes we don't know how to ask the question until we have found the answer :) would you mind linking me to some similar posts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this does not workis because your `group or group1 or group2 or group3 in user.groups.all()` is parsed as `(group) or (group1) or (group2) or (group3 in user.groups.all())`, and thus it will evaluate the truthiness of the `group` object. Normally these objects have by default truthiness `True`, and therefore the condition will always succeed.

We however do not need to use all those queries, we can check this with a single query. Indeed:

```
@register.filter(name='is_supervisor')
def is_in_group(user):
    return Group.objects.filter(
        user=user,
        name__in=[
            'security supervisor',
            'cage supervisor',
            'casino supervisor',
            'food bev supervisor'
        ]
    ).exists()
```

Comment: The first filter does work (I tested by moving the variable which causes `True` into different groups) -  though it looks ugly. The one you posted is much more pythonic and that is exactly what I was looking for. I am trying to learn to write in the best way possible.

Comment: When you say "all those queries" and "a single query" are you saying that my code was making 4 separate calls to the db and yours is only making one call?

Comment: @DavidAlford: exactly. The number of "roundtrips" to the database is reduced to one.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that `group_names_list` must exist and it would be outside of the function (at least this way the name of function makes sense). So you can implement the function like this:

```
@register.filter(name='is_supervisor')
def is_in_groups(user, group_names_list):
    result = False
    for group_name in group_names_list:
        result = result or Group.objects.get(name=group_name) in user.groups.all()
    return result
```

and pass the `group_names_list` to the function:

```
group_names_list = ['security supervisor', 'cage supervisor', 'casino supervisor', 'food bev supervisor']
```

---

**EDIT:** Thanks to @Willem Van Onsem, we can implement this function as:

```
@register.filter(name='is_supervisor')
def is_in_groups(user, group_names_list):
    return Group.objects.filter(user=user, name__in=group_names_list).exists()
```

Which I think must be more efficient.

Comment: This code is more readable to novice coders such as myself. Great edit!

Comment: I'm glad it helped :)